# How to send push notification from one device to another multiple device in android?

Tags: android, google-cloud-messaging

can any one knows how to send push notification from one device to multiple device. I create sample application. register for push notification and get the token by using code.I write php code for sending push notification i got notification on my device.but how to send the push notification from device to another multiple device.

Comment: Not possible. You need to manage it via your server

Answer (score 1):

Yes its possible.

Server is mandatory to implement.

Fetch All devices registration ids from Server then send push notifications to all devices.

**regID** is device GCM registration key

Use loop and change **regID**. Hope its helps you...

For Plain data:

```
            client = new DefaultHttpClient();
            httpPost = new HttpPost(SEND_URL);
            httpPost.setHeader("Authorization", "key=" + KEY);
            httpPost.setHeader("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=UTF-8");
            nvPair = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
            nvPair.add(new BasicNameValuePair("registration_id", regID));
            nvPair.add(new BasicNameValuePair("data1", "Push Notifications"));
            nvPair.add(new BasicNameValuePair("data2", "testting from another device"));
            httpPost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nvPair));
            res = client.execute(httpPost, new BasicResponseHandler());
```

For Json data:

```
            client = new DefaultHttpClient();
            httpPost = new HttpPost(SEND_URL);
            httpPost.setHeader("Authorization", "key=" + KEY);
            httpPost.setHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");
            obj = new JSONObject();
            obj.put("to", regID);
            innerObj = new JSONObject();
            innerObj.put("title", "Push Notification Title");
            innerObj.put("text", "Message");
            obj.put("notification", innerObj);
            httpPost.setEntity(new StringEntity(obj.toString()));
            Log.e("input", obj.toString() + " >>>end");
            res = client.execute(httpPost, new BasicResponseHandler());
```

Comment: please , can you explain properly i am not getting.

Comment: After successfully device registred into GCM, every device will receive REGISTRATION_ID, REGISTRATION_ID and username will be sent to server to store db. Using those REGISTRATION ids push notification will be sent by server to GCM Server. Then GCM Server will be sent push notification to device. Its PUSH NOTIFICATION flow...

Comment: Server have all devices REGISTRATION_IDs get those IDs and use my code. Then instead server your device will be sent notification to GCM server then GCM Server will be sent notifications to devices.

Comment: While this would work it is NOT recommended. This method will make your application insecure since anyone with access to your API key (which can be extracted from your APK) will be able to send messages to your application.

Answer (score 0):

No, it is not possible to send a push notification (GCM message) from one device to another (or multiple) device. You should use your application server as a relay.

Device1 > App Server > Device2/Device3/Device4...

You should **not** include the server API key used to send FCM messages in your Android app. That key should be secret and if extracted from your APK, anyone will be able to send messages to your application.